# How do infinite series contain "local" information?

Tags: sequences-and-series, number-theory, elliptic-curves

I would like to know why we consider infinite series (Dirichlet series, zeta function, elliptic curve $L$-series) or their Euler product. 
How is the local information "stored/contained" in the series/product and how we go about extracting the information?

It seems to me that the "local information" is stored in the coefficients, so why go through the trouble of taking infinite series and finding out if they can be continued analytically to the entire plane?

In short this is the question I'm asking:

How does looking at infinite series help us understand things locally?

If you could include an example in your answer, that would be super! Thanks!

Comment: The local information is encoded in the Euler factors (one factor per prime), but not all Dirichlet series have Euler products, so Dirichlet series are not equivalent to Euler products. The analytic continuation gives you information that you don't easily see from the original local information, roughly because the analytic continuation has a factorization over its zeros, so you can write the same function as a product over primes (Euler product) and a product over zeros (Hadamard factorization).  The main point of the infinite series is not to understand things locally, but globally.

Comment: Hi KCd, I've edited the post to reflect what you mentioned about the Euler products. Will you be able to expand your point with an example, showing what we can glean from the series that is not obtainable looking at local factors? Also, could you explain "analytic continuation has a factorization over its zeros, so you can write the same function as a product over primes (Euler product) and a product over zeros (Hadamard factorization)"? Thank you so much!

Comment: Did you look up what the Hadamard factorization is? Look at Wikipedia for "Explicit Formula", or search on that term in books that discuss zeta-functions. Another profound illustrate of the use of zeta-functions to tell us something global via the local information in the Euler products is the Birch and Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture. You tell us nothing about your background, so it's not clear at what level an answer would be meaningful to you (e.g., what do you know already about elliptic curves, number theory, or complex analysis?).

Comment: I've done courses on elliptic curves, algebraic number theory and analytic number theory, although I lean towards more towards the elliptic curve and algebraic side of things. So I can understand most of what you are saying(had to look up Hadamard and Explicit formula). BSD relates the $L$-function, made up of local factors, and something about the elliptic curve globally, ie the rank. We then use analytic continuation to show that it makes sense looking at the $L$-function at $s=1$. I think that about answers my question! Thanks for your time KCd!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm going to write up what KCd has said in the comments just for completeness sake. The point of using infinite series is not necessarily to obtain information locally but to understand things globally, which would make sense considering that we are combining local information when we do the infinite sum. Understanding things globally can then sometimes help us understand things locally.

The example is the Birch--Swinnerton-Dyer conjecture which says that the analytic rank is the same as the algebraic rank. The analytic rank being the order of the $L$-series which consists of local information. The conjecture then gives us the algebraic rank of the elliptic curve which is a global entity.